# EnhancedListView with ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, undo

I am using Tim Roes' EnhancedListView library , which is a listview with a combination of Swipe To Dismiss and Undo, in my project and it is working successfully. but I want the swipe to dismiss and undo capability in expandable list view and this library is only for simple listview. Is there any way I could include Swipe to Dismiss and Undo in my expandable list view?

Here is the link to the library:
[EnhancedListView](https://github.com/timroes/EnhancedListView)